# Golang decrypt PGP from openpgp.js

Tags: go, encryption

Need a help here with a symmetric PGP decryption in Golang, I've been trying to run symmetrical decryption on an encrypted hex generated on OpenPGP.js, unfortunately, no success to decrypt in Golang. This is the encryption in JS.

```js
const openpgp = require('openpgp')

async function main() {
  let options = {
    message: openpgp.message.fromBinary(new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x01, 0x01])), // input as Message object
    passwords: ['secret stuff'],                                             // multiple passwords possible
    armor: false                                                             // don't ASCII armor (for Uint8Array output)
  }

  const cypher_text = await openpgp.encrypt(options)
  const encrypted = cypher_text.message.packets.write()

  console.log(Buffer.from(encrypted).toString('hex'))

  options = {
    message: await openpgp.message.read(encrypted), // parse encrypted bytes
    passwords: ['secret stuff'],              // decrypt with password
    format: 'binary'                          // output as Uint8Array
  }

  const decrypted = await openpgp.decrypt(options)

  console.log(decrypted.data)
}

main()
```

console.log >>

```
c32e040903088c4db97456263252e0ef4f42627301e0ba3323b141a9ebd0476e5fe848d3c2b6021c8c06581ae2d19f7cd23b011b4b3a68758cb6fb12287db2a9ab6fdfad97670ae995e4deb7ca313d0aa705d264850adefb20353b263fc32ff8dc571f6dce8b722ddbdf40a907

Uint8Array [ 1, 1, 1 ]
```

My code is based on the following GIST https://gist.github.com/jyap808/8250124

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "errors"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp/armor"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp/packet"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp"
)

func main() {
    password := []byte("secret stuff")
    packetConfig := &packet.Config{
        DefaultCipher: packet.CipherAES256,
    }

    cypherHex := []byte("c32e040903088c4db97456263252e0ef4f42627301e0ba3323b141a9ebd0476e5fe848d3c2b6021c8c06581ae2d19f7cd23b011b4b3a68758cb6fb12287db2a9ab6fdfad97670ae995e4deb7ca313d0aa705d264850adefb20353b263fc32ff8dc571f6dce8b722ddbdf40a907")

    encbuf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    w, err := armor.Encode(encbuf, openpgp.SignatureType, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    w.Write(cypherHex)
    encbuf.Read(cypherHex)
    w.Close()

    log.Println(encbuf)

    decbuf := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(encbuf.String()))
    armorBlock, err := armor.Decode(decbuf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed on decode %+v\n", err)
    }

    failed := false
    prompt := func(keys []openpgp.Key, symmetric bool) ([]byte, error) {
        if failed {
            return nil, errors.New("decryption failed")
        }
        return password, nil
    }

    md, err := openpgp.ReadMessage(armorBlock.Body, nil, prompt, packetConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed on read message %+v\n", err)
    }

    plaintext, err := ioutil.ReadAll(md.UnverifiedBody)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed on read all body %+v\n", err)
    }

    log.Println(plaintext)
}
```

I noticed after log the encbuf that the armored key is kind of incomplete

```
2020/01/24 22:51:54 jcwYWU5
OTVlNGRlYjdjYTMxM2QwYWE3MDVkMjY0ODUwYWRlZmIyMDM1M2IyNjNmYzMyZmY4
ZGM1NzFmNmRjZThiNzIyZGRiZGY0MGE5MDc=
=9ciH
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

Update: Trying to decrypt without armor as well, if fails with EOF

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp/packet"
)

func main() {
    password := []byte("secret stuff")
    packetConfig := &packet.Config{
        DefaultCipher: packet.CipherAES128,
    }

    cypherHex := []byte("c32e040903088c4db97456263252e0ef4f42627301e0ba3323b141a9ebd0476e5fe848d3c2b6021c8c06581ae2d19f7cd23b011b4b3a68758cb6fb12287db2a9ab6fdfad97670ae995e4deb7ca313d0aa705d264850adefb20353b263fc32ff8dc571f6dce8b722ddbdf40a907")

    encbuf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    encbuf.Read(cypherHex)

    prompt := func(keys []openpgp.Key, symmetric bool) ([]byte, error) {
        return password, nil
    }

    md, err := openpgp.ReadMessage(encbuf, nil, prompt, packetConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed on read message %+v\n", err)
    }

    plaintext, err := ioutil.ReadAll(md.UnverifiedBody)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed on read all body %+v\n", err)
    }

    log.Println(plaintext)
}
```

Comment: Also the encrypted message to be decrypted is `c32e040903088c4db97456263252e0ef4f42627301e0ba3323b141a9ebd0476e5fe848d3c2b6021c8c06581ae2d19f7cd23b011b4b3a68758cb6fb12287db2a9ab6fdfad97670ae995e4deb7ca313d0aa705d264850adefb20353b263fc32ff8dc571f6dce8b722ddbdf40a907`

Comment: Please put the actual code you've tried in the question itself, and the actual problem you're facing. The linked code looks ok as a start, so please describe the what you expect to happen, and what actually happens.

Comment: Thanks! I just added my current implementation I think I'm close to solve the issue and decode, is something related with the armor, the encoded cipher didn't use armor, so I have to wrap into a armor in order to Go's OpenPGP implementation to parse correctly

Comment: The message isn’t signed, so don’t try to add signature armor. Just read the message.

Comment: Without the armor it gives the EOF error while trying to read the message

Comment: Thanks @JimB I think I got confused io.Reader interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're not decoding the hex-encoded ciphertext. Use the `encoding/hex` package to decode the data:

```
ct, err := hex.DecodeString(`c32e040903088c4db97456263252e0ef4f42627301e0ba3323b141a9ebd0476e5fe848d3c2b6021c8c06581ae2d19f7cd23b011b4b3a68758cb6fb12287db2a9ab6fdfad97670ae995e4deb7ca313d0aa705d264850adefb20353b263fc32ff8dc571f6dce8b722ddbdf40a907`)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Next problem is that you're incorrectly creating the `bytes.Buffer`. You're putting no data into the buffer, then calling the `Read` method which does nothing (and of you did initialize it with data, `Read` would "read" all the data out before you decrypt it anyway). The buffer could be initialized with the data, or filled using the `Write` method -- in this case you only need an `io.Reader` and can use `bytes.NewReader`.

```
r := bytes.NewReader(ct)
```

Finally, you now have 3 `0x01` bytes, which you can see more clearly using a better formatting:

```
d, err := ioutil.ReadAll(md.UnverifiedBody)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%#v\n", d)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Y3VqADQvEIH

Comment: Thanks @JimB that's exactly what I was looking for